# Why AVPlayer not stopping on the last frame of HLS streamed video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, avplayer

I have used to stitchedStreamPlayer to play stream video. However, i am not able to stop on last frame of video. It is showing black screen. I set the property

```
[player setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause];
```

still is not stopping video on the last frame. How should i stop on the last frame?

Comment: I am having the same issue here, any solution? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent so much time on this  I confirmed my video track is longer than the audio track but it still doesn’t stop at the last frame. I came up with a horrible hack to make this work though:

```
// Store as an instance variable so your observation sticks around
private var timeObservation: Any?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timeObservation = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: .main) { [weak self] time in
        self?.updateTime(time)
    }
}

private func updateTime(_ time: CMTime) {
    guard let item = player.currentItem else {
        return
    }

    // Assuming the video is 30fps and subtracting two frames. One wasn't enough for me.
    let offset = CMTime(seconds: 2 / 30, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))

    // If it's about to play past the end minus our offset, just stop
    if time >= item.duration - offset {
        player.pause()
        player.seek(to: item.duration - offset)
        return
    }
}
```

Other Things I Tried

Before I started using HLS, I still couldn't get it to pause at the last frame and was using `AVAssetImageGenerator` to get the last frame and show it in an image view. This looked a little jumpy and the compression/colors looked different from the playing video to the thumbnail.

I also saw some approaches where you could add an output to the player and then use that to make an image. I considered trying to do that just at the end but I think just stopping when you detect you need the image is a lot easier.

Hopefully this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is caused by longer audio track.
Below script fixes the last .ts file.

```
last_ts=$(ls -1 "$dir"/out_*.ts | sort | tail -1)
bak=$last_ts.bak
filename="${last_ts##*/}"
basename="${filename%.*}"
workdir=/tmp

# copy only on the first run
[ -f "$bak" ] || cp -r "$last_ts" "$bak"

ffmpeg -y -i "$bak" -vn -c:a copy "$workdir/${basename}_a.ts"

video_stream_info="$(ffprobe "$bak" 2>&1 | grep 'Stream #0:0')"
resolution=$(echo "$video_stream_info" | perl -pe 's/^.*?, ([0-9]*x[0-9]*).*$/\1/g')
fps=$(echo "$video_stream_info" | perl -pe 's/^.*?([0-9.]*) fps.*$/\1/g')
bitrate=""
# FIXME
if [ $quality = low ];then
    bitrate=400k
elif [ $quality = mid ];then
    bitrate=900k
elif [ $quality = high ];then
    bitrate=1200k
fi
extended_duration=$(ffprobe "$bak" 2>&1 | perl -ne '/Duration: (\d*):(\d*):(\d*)\.(\d*)/ && print((((((int($1) * 60) + int($2)) * 60) + int($3)) * 100 + int($4) + 10)/100)')

ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i nullsrc=s=${resolution}:d=${extended_duration}:r=${fps} -i "$bak" \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay[video]" -map "[video]" \
       -b:v $bitrate -c:v libx264 -an "$workdir/${basename}_v.ts"

ffmpeg -y -i "$workdir/${basename}_v.ts" -i "$workdir/${basename}_a.ts" \
       -c:a copy -c:v copy \
       "$last_ts"
```

Comment: In my case, the audio track is definitely shorter than the video track in my last `.ts` but it still doesn't show the last frame